# Running Android Emulator Headless on Docker on Apple Silicon

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, android-espresso, apple-silicon

I'm trying to setup a CI/CD chain for an Android app.  Getting unit tests to work is easy, so now I'm working on setting up instrumented tests.  However, when I try to setup the emulator in Docker I'm having problems.  The docker image I'm using is [cimg/android:2023.10.2-ndk](https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/android).  I'm using Apple Silicon, but the Docker image is x86-64.  In any case, I can't run the emulator because "x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!".  Does anyone know how to get around this?

Here are my steps:

```
sdkmanager --verbose "system-images;android-32;google_apis;x86_64"
avdmanager create avd -n jbtest -k "system-images;android-32;google_apis;x86_64" -d "Nexus 7"
emulator -no-audio -no-window -avd jbtest
```

Complete output:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/circleci/android-sdk/system-images/android-32/google_apis/x86_64/
INFO    | Crashreporting disabled, not reporting crashes.
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /home/circleci/.android/avd/jbtest.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
ERROR   | x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
```

Is it just not possible to do this?  If so, I'm surprised that, being as mature as it is, that Android instrumented testing doesn't work in CI/CD pipelines.